# How to navigate into sections with angular router?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

How can I navigate to a specific section of an HTML on Angular 2? I want to navigate as follows:

```html
<a href="#first">First section</a></li>
<a href="#second">Second section</a></li>
<a href="#third">Third section</a></li>

<section id="first">
  Content...
</section <section id="second">
Content...
</section>
<section id="third">
  Content...
</section>
```

but with Angular router.

Comment: That should work. What's the problem? Are you using the router?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I want to do it with angular router because I'm migrating a static web page to an Angular 2 App. I have a navbar component that allows to navigate through the application but that does not work.

Comment: The router allows to pass a fragment https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#fragment

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Following that other page: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html I did this: `<a [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="first">Link to first section</a>` link it's correctly formed: localhost:4200/home#firstsection but not works.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. Might be a bug. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this in your router

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    scrollOffset: [0, 64],
  };




@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerOptions)], //ExtraOptions
    ...
  })
```

And Your anchor tag should be like this

```
<a 
  [routerLink]="['/yourPageLink', params]" fragment="first}">First section</a>
```

For Doc
Click [here](https://www.geekstrick.com/fragment-url-in-angular-8/)